# Reuse dataTable within scenario and feature

Tags: cucumber, bdd

Here is my feature file (for example)

```
Feature: The flower story
  I bought some flowers to make a bouquet to gift it to my friend

  Scenario: Make a bouquet
    Given I have the following flowers
      | Lotus   |
      | Jasmine |
      | Rose    |
    When I make a bouquet with the flowers
    Then the bouquet should have the below flowers
      | Lotus   |
      | Jasmine |
      | Rose    |

  Scenario: Gift bouquet to my friend
    Given I have a bouquet with the following flowers
      | Lotus   |
      | Jasmine |
      | Rose    |
    When I gift it to my friend
    And he unwraps the flowers from the bouquet
    Then My friend should have the below flowers
      | Lotus   |
      | Jasmine |
      | Rose    |
```

**Problem:** The flowers (dataTable) are repeating

**Question**: How can I reuse the data table (may with a place holder) to represent the flowers wherever I need? (assume I don't need Scenario Outline)

Comment: Adding related questions - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31561156/reusing-cucumber-data-tables

Answer (score 1):

*First, please focus more on this statement "**Cucumber is not a tool, it's a thought process**".Now lets see what is Scenario Outline first.*

***Scenario Outline :*** In short, multiple scenarios need to be executed having same pattern of steps with different input values.

*Hope, That’s much clearer. Now let's move to Data Table*

***Data Table :*** DT concept comes into picture for accessing test data with in step definitions methods from a specific/individual step of Scenario/Scenario Outline. Data Table is defined under a step not to some place where Data table becomes accessible for few/all steps.

*Would give you advise, for your scenario, Scenario Outline shall be the correct concept not Data Table. As per my understanding & knowledge, it's not possible defining Data Table under a placeholder and use for multiple steps as you mentioned.*

***More about Data Table :*** Sometimes steps in a scenario need to describe data that doesn’t easily fit on a single line of Given, When, or Then. Cucumber data table is one of the most commonly used methods for passing test data from feature files in tabular format. And you can then use this data in step definition methods in the form of Lists and Maps.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed description. Let's assume I don't have the second scenario. It is obvious that Scenario Outline is out of the picture. Now, if you look at my first scenario I have repeated the data twice (in two steps). Is there any suggested practice to avoid this duplicate?

Comment: As per my best knowledge and experience, any step can use data table defined under that step only, not from somewhere else. So if there is only 1 scenario and multiple steps need to execute common data table then it would be repeated as per count of steps going to use data table. Can not avoid these duplicates values.

Comment: Thing to understand here is, there is data table association for the steps under which we write data table and then that data association flows between steps in feature file and steps method implementation. So it had to be followed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Background:

```
Feature: The flower story
  I bought some flowers to make a bouquet to gift it to my friend

Background:
 Given I have the following flowers
      | Lotus   |
      | Jasmine |
      | Rose    |

  Scenario: Make a bouquet
    When I make a bouquet with the flowers
    Then the bouquet should have the below flowers
      | Lotus   |
      | Jasmine |
      | Rose    |

  Scenario: Gift bouquet to my friend
     When I gift it to my friend
    And he unwraps the flowers from the bouquet
    Then My friend should have the below flowers
      | Lotus   |
      | Jasmine |
      | Rose    |
```